# ASP.NET MVC 5 Attribute Routing: Url.Action returns null when using multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This kind of question has been asked before on SO ([post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800618/asp-net-mvc-5-attribute-routing-url-action-returns-null), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302970/mvc5-url-action-returns-null-inside-area/36303434), [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479565/mvc-url-action-returning-null-or-url-as-get)), but none of them was able to help me.

I have the following route (defined inside a `LandingController` class):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("connections/{city:name}/map{page?}", Order = 2)]
public Task<ActionResult> Connections(string city, int page = 1)
```

for which I am trying to generate an URL in my Razor template like this:

```
@Url.Action("Connections", "Landing", new { city = "madrid", page = 1 })
```

or

```
@Url.Action("Connections", new { city = "madrid", page = 1 })
```

Both these calls return `null`. Anyone has an idea why?

However if I omit the page parameter in the route template (doing  `[Route("connections/{city:name}/map", Order = 2)]`), the following URL is generated: `/connections/madrid/map/?page=1`, which is not what I want, but it shows that I am doing something wrong with my calls above.

Comment: can you also show how the route is defined in your routeconfig?

Comment: My route is defined using attribute routing, i.e. above the action method (which I have posted in the question), so it's not in a routeconfig.

Comment: Could you try `[Route("connections/{city:name}/map/{page?}]`?

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? Would love to see your solution!

Comment: @GlenLittle I was able to solve this. We use culture-specific URLs depending on `CurrentCulture` and it turned out that the routing info for that specific culture was not set up in the database where we keep our routing configuration, and I kept getting `null`s. Basically, getting null from `@Url.Action` means that the route you are looking for has not been configured and does not exist. I was not aware that we saved route configs in the database at the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("connections/{city:name}/map{page?}", Order = 2)]
public Task<ActionResult> Connections(string city, int page = 1)
```

Pretty sure your routing is incorrect, `{city:name}` what is name? I don't recall any having a constraint type name.

Your attribute routing should be as simple as this:

```
[Route("connections/{city}/map/{page?}", Order = 2)]
```

If you want to add constraint to page as integer it would be:

```
[Route("connections/{city}/map/{page:int?}", Order = 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even when I remove the `name` constraint, I still get `null`, I tried that already...

Comment: Should of worked, however I am curious do you have a similar routing in your controller that may be causing a conflict?

Comment: No, I checked. If I call the URL which I am expecting to be generated (`connections/{city:name}/map1`) and I run the debugger, the breakpoint set inside the action implementation is hit - so definitely no conflicts.

Comment: Can you confirm that your `@Url.Action("Connections", new { city = "madrid", page = 1 })` is actually generating the correct url as `route data` and not `querystrings`? I got a feeling that it's generating `http://localhost/landing/connections?city=madrid?page=1`

Comment: `@Url.Action("Connections", new { city = "madrid", page = 1 })` always returns `null`, that's what the question is about..